# Dash app not loading local CSS file when run in VS Code

Tags: python, html, css, plotly-dash

I am developing a Dash application using VS Code and encountering an issue where my local CSS file is not being loaded. When I run the app and access it via `http://localhost:8080/`, the browser console displays the following error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/.../assets/custom_style.css

The CSS file is located in the `assets` folder, as per the Dash documentation. Here's how I'm running the app:

```py
# main.py
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, '/assets/custom_style.css'])
# ... rest of the code ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=8080)
```

I tried to run it in VS code and also in GCP

I am getting error code 500 in GCP and 404 in vs code.

I also wanted to let you guys know that I got it to run a few days ago. Custom.css file was getting applied to the web page. but now, no matter what I do, I am getting errors. CHATGPT was of no help.

And I'm accessing the app through the URL provided by the Dash server (http://127.0.0.1:8080/).

I have tried the following without success:

Clearing the browser cache and force-refreshing the page.
Ensuring there are no typos in the CSS file name.
Moving the project directory outside of the OneDrive sync folder.